# Can anyone guide me how to achieve below scenario

Tags: plsql, oracle11g

I have source and target tables with some calculation as I mentioned below, I want to populate result set of the calculation from the source table into the destination table.

Columns in destination table are enabled `NOT NULL` constraint.

Can anyone guide me to achieve below requirement.

**SOURCE TABLE:**

**Source_table1** >>

```
col1,
col2,
col3
```

**Source_table2** >>

```
col1,
col2,
col3
```

**TARGET TABLE:**

**Dest_table:**

```
col1 >> Source_table1.col1+Source_table2.col1

col2 >> Source_table1.col2+Source_table2.col2

col3 >>  Dest_table.col1+Dest_table.col2

col4 >> Source_table1.col3+Source_table1.col3+Dest_table.col3
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you try to come up with a query or expecting us to write the whole query?. And there is no need of plsql. Try using simple `insert into target select  * from source`  with joins and sub-queries. you will sure get help here if you face difficulty. Important thing is to try and post the query if you have tried any.

Comment: Thanks for suggestion kaushik, I have tried in PL/SQL, and i achieved col1, col2, col3 of the destination table. Still i didn't get any ideas to achieve the calculation made on COL4 of the Dest_table. If you don't mind on your suggestion, if i do that in your way, i would get col1 and col2 i won't get col3, col4 of the Dest_table . In that way i will get invalid identifier . And i don't have any proper relation between the source and destination table.  Pls correct me if i wrong on anywhere on your suggestion.   Thanks

Comment: How are `source_table1`  and `source_table2`   linked ?. I mean do they have same rows or multiple rows in `source_table2` for each record in `source_table1` or vice versa.. ?Show some sample records of data from each source table.

Comment: I mean to say, these are the sample tables, source_tab1 and source_tab2 have relation(lets take relation like this, source_tab1.seq_no = source_tab2.seq_no ) and the result of the source table to populate into dest_table.Between the source_tables(source_tab1, source_tab2) and destination table have no relation( source_tab1.seq_no = source_tab2.seq_no and dest_tab(no relation)).

Answer (score 0):

All you need is three layers of summations, something as shown below. A simple `Insert into select` should work than going for a PL/SQL block. And as per one of your comments, `source_tab1.seq_no = source_tab2.seq_no` is the join condition between the source tables.

```
INSERT INTO Dest_table (col1,
                        col2,
                        col3,
                        col4)
   SELECT dcol1,
          dcol2,
          dcol3,
          s1col3 + s2col3 + dcol3 dcol4
     FROM (SELECT dcol1,
                  dcol2,
                  dcol1 + dcol2 dcol3,
                  s1col3,
                  s2col3
             FROM (SELECT s1col1 + s2col1 dcol1,
                          s1col2 + s2col2 dcol2,
                          s1col3,
                          s2col3
                     FROM (SELECT s1.col1 s1col1,
                                  s1.col2 s1col2,
                                  s1.col3 s1col3,
                                  s2.col1 s2col1,
                                  s2.col2 s2col2,
                                  s2.col3 s2col3
                             FROM source_table1 s1
                                  JOIN source_table2 s2
                                     ON s1.seq_no = s2.seq_no)));
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer Kaushik. The reason  why i'm going with PL/SQL, here i know what is source table, destination table, columns and it's calculation. But my requirement is, i need to populate same thing from source to destination but i never know what is source/destination tables and it's column and calculation. All values i need to get at run time. I made all calculation on dest_table except col4, Here only i got struck how to deal. Now i got some idea, i'll make it dynamic and i come back if have any doubt. thanks Kaushik for your time.